# Why admin can't add himself to project member in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

My account on gitlab is Admin. I can't add myself as member to projects created by other users. Gitlab doesn't show any errors. Simply no effects after pressing "Add users to project"

Project owner can add my account to members with no problems. I can add another users to projects. But not myself.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, funny.

Obviously the administrator account is not meant to be used for projects. You should create a non-admin account for that.

It is possible to create projects as administrator though. The silent failure of adding to a project is probably a bug.